# TS выдает ошибку (Argument of type '(value: unknown) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

TS выдает ошибку (Argument of type '(value: unknown) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.).
Подчеркивает переменную resolve.

```
const wait = (timeout: number) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
  });
};
```

Можете подсказать пожалуйста, как решить подобную проблему?

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gQwJawLwwBRSQWwKYgCuUAXDGITgEZ4BOAlDKgHwwDeAsAFAwy15RCtMOTxwYABVogcSCHgz8IIADYA3PE1acevGPKgAVXAWKK8y9XgA0MbPiJR6Abm68Avi+7vXXbohQMAFYABhCYFyA) пожалуйста, не показывает той ошибки, о которой вы пишете

Comment: тут не показывает ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам следует вызвать функцию `resolve` в колбэке в `setTimeout`

```typescript
const wait = (timeout: number) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), timeout);
  });
};
```